# How to cycle through JSON with multiple records in Delphi

Tags: json, rest, delphi-11-alexandria

When receiving JSON such as the example below, how do I cycle through to extract each field value of each "record", so I can insert them into a database?

```
{
  "Accounts": [{
    "AccountID": "ebd06280-af70-4bed-97c6-7451a454ad85",
    "Code": "091",
    "Name": "Business Savings Account",
    "Type": "BANK",
    "TaxType": "NONE",
    "EnablePaymentsToAccount": false,
    "BankAccountNumber": "0209087654321050",
    "BankAccountType": "BANK",
    "CurrencyCode": "NZD"
  },{
    "AccountID": "7d05a53d-613d-4eb2-a2fc-dcb6adb80b80",
    "Code": "200",
    "Name": "Sales",
    "Type": "REVENUE",
    "TaxType": "OUTPUT2",
    "Description": "Income from any normal business activity",
    "EnablePaymentsToAccount": false
  }]
}
```

This is what I have so far, but I'm getting an error on the ParseJSONValue line - "Invalid class typecast"

```
try
  xeroRequest.Execute;
  if Assigned(xeroResponse.JSONValue) then begin
    jValue := xeroResponse.JSONValue;
    strJson := jValue.ToString;
    jArray := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(strJson) as TJSONArray;
    try
      idx := 1;
      for arrElement in jArray do begin
        RowValue := (arrElement as TJSonObject).GetValue('Accounts');
        if RowValue is TJSONArray then begin
          for RowItem in TJSONArray(RowValue) do begin
            RowItem.TryGetValue('AccountID', AcctId);
            memoJson.Lines.Add(Format('%d: %s', [idx, AcctId]));
          end;
        end;
        inc(idx);
      end;
    finally
      jArray.Free;
    end;
  end;
except on E:Exception do
  ShowMessage('Error: ' + xeroResponse.ErrorMessage + ' - ' + E.Message);
end;
```

Comment: What JSON library are you using to process the JSON? What have you attempted so far to iterate the records that is not working for you? The JSON consists of 1 object whose `Accounts` field is an array of objects. Any JSON library will easily let you access that array and iterate it. But the syntax to do so is going to differ between libraries.

Comment: I am using the standard Delphi 11 Rest components :   TRESTClient, TRESTRequest, TRESTResponse. I haven't really tried anything yet, as I'm unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: That kind of information belonged in the question to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `TRESTResponse` to get the JSON. You can typecast its `JSONValue` property to `TJSONObject` and read the `Accounts` value from it, then typecast that value to `TJSONArray` and iterate it, typecasting each element to `TJSONObject` and read fields from that object as needed.

---

**UPDATE**: You don't need to parse the JSON, it's already been parsed for you. Just use the `TRESTResponse.JSONValue` as-is, it points at the top-level value of the parsed JSON.

As for the typecast error, it's because you are casting the `JSONValue` to `TJSONArray`, which is wrong as the JSON does not begin with an array (`[...]` ). It begins with an object (`{...}`), so you have to cast the `JSONValue` to `TJSONObject` first, as I stated above.

Also, DO NOT free any of the JSON items at all. You don't own any of them, the top-level `TJSONObject` pointed by `JSONValue` owns them, and the `TRESTResponse` owns the `JSONValue`.

Try this instead:

```pascal
try
  xeroRequest.Execute;
  if Assigned(xeroResponse.JSONValue) then begin
    jObject := xeroResponse.JSONValue as TJSONObject;
    jArray := jObject.GetValue('Accounts') as TJSONArray;
    idx := 1;
    for arrElement in jArray do begin
      jObject := arrElement as TJSONObject;
      jObject.TryGetValue('AccountID', AcctId);
      memoJson.Lines.Add(Format('%d: %s', [idx, AcctId]));
      Inc(idx);
    end;
  end;
except
  on E:Exception do
    ShowMessage('Error: ' + xeroResponse.ErrorMessage + ' - ' + E.Message);
end;
```

Comment: I've edited the original question to show what I've tried, but I'm getting a class typecast error.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please re-read it more carefully. You didn't do what I told you to do. In fact, you're not accessing the JSON data in any way I described.